# When I Style Form Input File - I cannot get it to upload when with Submit Button

Tags: css, forms, input-type-file

I have "successfully" styled my File Type Input using codeDrops Styling & Customizing Tutorial by Osvaldas Valutis. But with using this method or any method I have used prior, when I submit the form the file does not upload. When I leave type file input untouched, it works. So I do not know why the Submit button is not processing the image info to the next page. When you browse and choose image using the styling methods, the image name appears as it should in the button. But the submit button when clicked will not carry over the image data.

HTML:

```
<form action="exifdata.php" name="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form">
<div class="box1">
<input type="file" name="file-1" id="file-1" class="inputfile inputfile-1" accept="image/*" />
<label for="file-1"><span>Choose Your Photo&hellip;</span></label>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Upload For Editing" id="submit-btn" onClick="validateForm();"/><br/><br/>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.inputfile {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.box1 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.inputfile + label {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: #3a58a6;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    height: 35px;
    width: 230px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: thin solid gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px gray;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.inputfile:focus + label,
.inputfile + label:hover {
    background-color: #eedb02;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px gray;
    color: black;
}
.inputfile + label {
    cursor: pointer; /* "hand" cursor */
}
.inputfile:focus + label {
    outline: 1px dotted #000;
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
.inputfile + label * {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
'use strict';

;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
{
    $( '.inputfile' ).each( function()
    {
        var $input   = $( this ),
            $label   = $input.next( 'label' ),
            labelVal = $label.html();

        $input.on( 'change', function( e )
        {
            var fileName = '';

            if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 )
                fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
            else if( e.target.value )
                fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();

            if( fileName )
                $label.find( 'span' ).html( fileName );
            else
                $label.html( labelVal );
        });

        // Firefox bug fix
        $input
        .on( 'focus', function(){ $input.addClass( 'has-focus' ); })
        .on( 'blur', function(){ $input.removeClass( 'has-focus' ); });
    });
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Remember, when I take off the styling, it works. But when I try to style a file type input, the input + label method works; but the file data does not get preserved through the form submitting process for the next page.

Comment: When you say "take off the styling", what do you mean? Do you remove the CSS only or do you remove the JavaScript as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<button type="submit" value="Upload For Editing" id="submit-btn" onClick="validateForm();"/><br/><br/>
```